# export csv with dynamic file name

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby, data-analysis

```
files = glob.glob("dataset_missing*.csv")
for f in files:
    df = pd.read_csv(f, na_values = missing_values, nrows=10)
    df.fillna(df.mean(), inplace=True)
    print(f)
    #print(df)
    export_csv = df.to_csv ("F:\Result_Check\"+"B933418"+"f.csv", index = None, header=True) 
    print("Next File")
```

I am getting error while exporting. I would like to save the file with FileName and ID. Kindly help me on this

Comment: what is the error? plz add the error in your question

Comment: File "<ipython-input-19-8237f8125282>", line 35
  ````  export_csv = df.to_csv ("F:\Result_Check\"+"B033418"+"f.csv", index = None, header=True)
                                                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Maybe it should be +V00933418+ without extra "

Comment: I am getting an error while fetching the file name from for loop.  f.csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try composing the filename like this:

```
import os
filename = os.path.join('F:', 'Result_Check', 'B933418' + f + '.csv')
```

Also you do not normally assign result of df.to_csv to a variable.

Comment: Kindly remove/change the ID in your previous answer. Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi Evgeny, thanks for your quick response. Kindly help me to remove my id from your first answer.

Comment: What exactly is id? A part of the filename? Canyou give the examples of the filenames you work with?

Comment: ID which starts with V0. from your answer "Maybe it should"

Comment: What is the result of glob.glob("dataset_missing*.csv")?

Comment: It will list all the csv files in that location.

Comment: can your remove that ID. in your first comment.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot understand what you are asking - if there is some extra transformation you would like to do, perhaps better ask separate question. In that question please indicate your starting state of a string, expected result and what you tried snd how it fails. Without asking a question properly you leave people confused.