# Is there a way to name a new data frame given i from a for loop?

Tags: python, pandas

I hope the question is clear enough. I have one giant data set (30 mil+) and would like to split it up into 8 smaller ones.

Is there a way to name a data frame based on the i in the for loop?

So for example if I have a list with `lst = ['machine_1', 'machine_2', 'machine_3']` and I would like to create dataframes for each of these, is it possible to get them so that the data frames are called `df_machine_1, df_machine_2` and `df_machine_3`?

Something like:

```
lst = ['machine_1', 'machine_2', 'machine_3']

for i in lst:
    df_i = df[df['Machines'] == i]]
```

I know that this doesn't work, but is there another solution?

Comment: this may help :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58055458/export-csv-with-dynamic-file-name

Comment: Not really to be hones, but I do see that it seems like a bad idea so I will do it manually. Thanks for the speedy reply

Answer (score 0):

You could also consider making a dictionary with dict comprehension:

```
dfs = {i:df[df['Machines']==i] for i in lst}
```

And call them via their key, for example: `dfs['machine_1']`

Comment: It misses a "]" after the "==i" ;)